# What is the difference between /usr/include/ and /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/?

Tags: deepin

I want to find the utmp.h, but there are two different virsion

Comment: Open those files, you can see this `#error "Never include <bits/utmp.h> directly; use <utmp.h> instead."`.

Answer (score 2):

The header files in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/` are included by a corresponding header in `/usr/include/`. If I open up `/usr/include/utmp.h` on my machine and go to lines 28 and 29, I'll find:

```c
/* Get system dependent values and data structures.  */
#include <bits/utmp.h>
```

This means that the `bits` headers are used to define data structures and preprocessor macros that differ between systems. These definitions can then be used by the standard `/usr/include` headers, instead of having to create and distribute different `/usr/include` headers for every possible system configuration.